# What area of Los Angeles does this historical map depict?

Tags: 19th-century, geography, maps

What area of Los Angeles does [this historical map](http://ids.lib.harvard.edu/ids/view/8608878?viewheight=2256&height=2256&width=2400&viewwidth=2400) depict?

[image: Plan of Los Angeles]

Comment: Please note, some of the existing street names are on your map.

Answer (score 2):

That appears to be the survey of LA drawn out by [Lieutenant Edward Ord](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Ord) in 1849.

If so, then the Fort Street in the grid-like area in the upper left area of the map later became [Broadway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadway_%28Los_Angeles%29) street. Hill Street, the next over from Fort Street on the survey, is still the next street NW from Broadway today.

As for where on Broadway that is, I'd say its almost certainly [centered around 1'st St](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=los%20angeles&ll=34.052571,-118.240721&spn=0.011556,0.016458&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-a&hnear=Los%20Angeles,%20California&gl=us&t=m&z=16). For one thing, LA's grid bends a bit there much like the bend on this map. But more importantly, cities tend to grow outward, with the center of their downtowns typically occupying the area of original settlement.